# Is there a magic item in 5e dnd that increases crit range and if not would it be op?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew, critical-hit

I’m very new to 5e but I’ve played pathfinder and 3.5 for quite a while so I was wondering is there an item that increases crit range for melee or ranged weapons and if not how powerful would a magic item that increases crit range (and maybe some skills or attributes or anything similar) be for a 7th level character onwards as my DM has allowed me to get an item of any rarity(with vetos) with hombrew (also note it would be unstackable with other crit threat increaseing abilities)

Comment: It's kind of hard for us to say whether something is OP or balanced if we don't have any actual content to review. Increases the crit range *to* what? What other skills or attributes or anything similar does it *actually* increase as well or otherwise? Does it require attunement? I suggest actually creating an item and *then* asking whether it's balanced. See [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/14878) for what kind of information we expect.

Comment: Alternately, a question about whether or not there is an existing item that has this effect would definitely be answerable.

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165899/what-should-be-the-rarity-of-this-homebrew-critical-chance-item seems pertinent.

Comment: I will note that giving a 7th-level character their legendary-rarity item of choice is... bold, at bare minimum.  It i likely to deform the game at least a little.

Comment: I think this may be a few too many questions.  I'd suggest simplifying this one down to the "does this exist" part, reading the linked Q&A, and then proposing a homebrew item as a different question.  Questions tht say "suggest this for me" are off-topic here.  Questions that say "I have this item.  Is it balanced?" are legit, and often also get suggestions for tweaks.

Comment: @Iter [please don’t answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).

Answer (score -1):

Champion Fighters already get the expanded crit range. So I suppose if you wanted to homebrew an item that replicates that, you could make it's rarity/cost/etc directly proportional to the level of the class feature.

> **Improved Critical**
>
> Beginning when you choose this archetype at 3rd level, your weapon
> attacks score a critical hit on a roll of 19 or 20.
>
> **Superior Critical**
>
> Starting at 15th level, your weapon attacks score a critical hit on a
> roll of 18–20.

Would it be OP? *IMO, absolutely yes it would be OP*. If for no other reason than it opens up the possibility of having a Fighter with a crit range of 16-20.

But that's just me.

Comment: Actually, crit roll ranges wouldn't "stack" in 5th edition, so a "Sword of Crits" that made criticals on a 19 or 20 wielded by a 3rd level Champion fighter would _still_ just have a crit range of 19 or 20. What it _would_ do is take away the entire raison d'etre of being a Champion fighter by allowing a different (sub)class to use their main feature (which is always an indicator of "overpowered-ness" to me).

Comment: A Moonblade (source: DMG) has the chance to grant a crit-range of 19-20 for attacks made with it. Given that exists, along with the Champion Fighter's 3rd level ability to do the same of all attacks, it doesn't seem gamebreaking.However, it's largely up to the GM as to what items are available,