# How rare is this artificer magic item I created?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew-review

One of my backup characters is a level 10 gnome artificer and has some self made magic items, but I roleplay it as if it's a technological swiss army knife with different functions with 3 buttons. (using an item interaction to switch modes)

By default the item is her tinkers tools (artisan tools).
**The 1st button turns the item into a stim-pistol**, giving her the ability to use the healers kit from 30 ft. away.
**The 2nd button turns it into a tiny taser-pistol** infused with repeating shot which uses intelligence for to hit with a 1d4+int dmg modifier, with as a special effect: **(recharge 5-6)** When you hit a creature with your taser pistol, it must succeed on a constitution saving throw of 18 (8+int+PB+1) or be paralyzed until the end of their next turn.
**The 3rd button turns it back into her default item**

I was wondering how rare the stim-pistol and the taser-pistol would be individually (ignoring the fact that the DM allowed me to infuse the taser for the rule of cool).

Comment: Are other players getting homebrew items? If so, can you let us know what those are and what rarity was assigned?

Comment: Also, I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Are you asking what the rarity of an item that does all three is, or three separate items? I'm pretty sure it's the former, right?

Comment: Very related on [Is item rarity really tied to how powerful it is?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136557/is-item-rarity-really-tied-to-how-powerful-it-is)

Comment: Also related: "[How is the power of a magic item measured according to the rules?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136571)"

Comment: my question got closed, and it told me to either edit it or repost it, so i edited it based on the feedback i already got, since i wasn't allowed to post a new question for a while.

Comment: @Tango_The_Bee You should edit the question based on what details were requested from comments, not based on feedback from answers.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit for now, as iterations of homebrew reviews should be posted as new questions [at least 72 hours](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9151/62294) after the first posting. The details I wanted to see for reopening were answers to NautArch's two comments [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188787/how-rare-is-this-artificer-magic-item-i-created#comment508566_188787) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188787/how-rare-is-this-artificer-magic-item-i-created#comment508567_188787)

Comment: Relevant Q&As on Meta: [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/33569), [How should I ask about my D&D 5e Homebrew being balanced?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8171/33569)

Comment: Could we clarify specifically what this author can do to get their question reopened? I've opened a meta to that effect: [What does the author to this item rarity question need to actually do to get their question reopened?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11645/what-does-the-author-to-this-item-rarity-question-need-to-actually-do-to-get-the)

Comment: In the hope of improving the clarity, I've moved the comments which weren't outstanding requests (or similarly important) [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127349/discussion-on-question-by-tango-the-bee-how-rare-is-this-artificer-magic-item-i).

Answer (score 4):

### Stim-pistol: Uncommon

### Taser-pistol: Very Rare

You could think of the stim-pistol as having an effect which is slightly more powerful than the cantrip [Spare the Dying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spare-the-dying), (because it doesn't require touch), but less powerful than the 1st level spell [Healing Word](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-word), (because it has less range, doesn't regain hit points and requires an action rather than a bonus action). Magic items which cast 1st level spells are usually uncommon. For example [Wand of Magic Missile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-magic-missiles), [Wand of Magic Detection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-magic-detection), or the [Wand of Entangle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-entangle).

The taser-pistol is arguably a better version of the rare item [Wand of Paralysis](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-paralysis), because it recharges faster, has a higher DC for saving throws, and also does damage. While it is not better in all circumstances - since it does require you to hit, and the paralysis only lasts until the end of their next turn; the fact that you can expect to be able to use this once or twice per combat would seem to warrant pushing it up to the very rare category.

Comment: You'll notice all those uncommon wands are not healing, that's a big area to step into that most things tend to avoid unless they are very high level. The recharge also provides an opportunity for use more than once/encounter, but it's definitely usable to 'recharge' always between encounters - that makes it much more powerful. Additionally, the healing with the Healer feat turns this into *Healing Word*, a 1st level spell that can be cast every short rest.

Comment: I would think it's actually *hold monster* rather than *person* since the paralyze effect isn't limited to humanoids.

Comment: would it be smarted for me to make the stim pistol just like the Circle of mortality from the grave cleric. i quote "you learn the Spare the Dying cantrip, which doesn't count against the number of cleric cantrips you know. For you, it has a range of 30 feet, and you can cast it as a bonus action.". That way the stim pistol won't be indirectly made stronger than it should be with the healer feat.

Comment: A very fair point about hold monster vs hold person; so my comparison wasn't applicable. I've edited to remove that point.

Answer (score 0):

### The Paralysis effect is way too good.

The "taser pistol" is functionally a one-round *hold monster* spell that you can use at least once in every fight. Even with the limited effect, Paralyzed is possibly the most devastating condition in the game on the PC side because of the "free crits!" sign it sticks on the target's head.

I'm not sure I can come up with a rarity for that; even if it were 'recharge on a short or long rest', it's probably Legendary, but it's hard to judge because of the lack of comparables.

At the very minimum I'd change that effect to Stunned, which is functionally identical except doesn't have the crit effect, and I'd probably recommend changing it to Restrained, or maybe even all the way down to the *shocking grasp* effect of just removing their reaction.

Comment: Thank  you for your feedback, now that you mention it like that even with the recharge it feels kind of strong to give a creature the paralyze condition with such a high DC. do you think it would help if i chance the condition to stunned, and make it so you have to call the effect before you roll for attack instead of after? since basically it maked sense you overcharge the taser before you fire the shot.

Comment: @Tango_The_Bee Comments aren't for really homebrew development and are a bit further away from your request for rarity. Unfortunately, we don't really do "help me homebrew this" here. If the item needs work, you'll do better working on that either in our very own [chat] or [a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449)